# Reorganise APFS container disks

Tags: macos, disk-utility, catalina, apfs

I have an internal SSD with 500 GB. Currently it is divided into two container disks, each with the size of 250 GB:

[image]

For some reason, I had originally allocated the first one as a backup, which I no longer think is a good idea. I have deleted the volume, but the container still remains.

Is it possible to merge the two containers without having to reformat the whole lot?

Here is the output of `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         249.4 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.6 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Preboot                 28.7 KB    disk1s2
   2:                APFS Volume Recovery                20.5 KB    disk1s3
   3:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +249.4 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume iMac — Data             200.7 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 79.2 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.1 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume iMac                    11.2 GB    disk2s5
```

Comment: Please post output of `diskutil list`.  If Container 1 is first you can't merge them - you'll have to copy contents of container 2 to container 1, then delete 2 and extend 1.

Comment: @lx07 I have included the output.

Comment: Just to be clear, you’ve got two containers on that one drive, both are 250GB each, correct?  You don’t want this any more and instead want just one container of 50GB? Do you have data on the container you want deleted?

Comment: Personnally I would backup everything on a separate drive then repartition and format etc from scratch.

Comment: @SolarMike I ended up doing something similar to that, but not so tedious. I cloned everything onto the first container (using SuperDuper), set that as my Startup volume, and afterwards deleted the second partition. Worked perfectly. I just thought APFS was smart enough to allow deleting the first container instead.